# MySQL INSERT Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have problem with my MySQL query:

```
include '../inc/mysql_config.php';
$sql="INSERT INTO ordrar 
        (id, order, namn, adress, postnummer, postort, email, status)
      VALUES
        (NULL, '$order','$namn','$adress','$postnummer', '$postort', '$email', '$email', '$status')";
 mysql_query($sql);
 if (!mysql_query($sql)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
```

This outputs:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order, namn, adress, postnummer,
>   postort, email, status) VALUES ' at
>   line 1

Thanks.

**Solved:**

```
    include '../inc/mysql_config.php';
    $sql="INSERT INTO ordrar (id, substans, namn, adress, postnummer, postort, email, status)
    VALUES
    (NULL, '$substans','$namn','$adress','$postnummer', '$postort', '$email', '$status')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    if (!mysql_query($sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
```

**Thanks everyone!**

Comment: You specify 8 columns and pass 9 values, with `email` value twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I count 8 column names and 9 values.  Is '$email' meant to be repeated?

"ORDER" might be a keyword - from ORDER BY SQL.  Maybe a quick column name change could fix it.  Try it and see.

Answer (score 7):

'order' is a reserved word.  You'll need to wrap it in backticks, but you'll have less headaches if you rename the column.

Answer (score 4):

8 rows, 9 query parameters - you have a duplicate $email variable in the VALUES portion of the INSERT statement.